# Free vector graphics package for Windows OR Linux

Tags: linux, graphics, windows, svg

What is the most popular and/or feature complete vector graphics package for Windows and/or Ubuntu Linux? I keep finding 'Vector Art' sites but nothing about the software used to create it. Adobe must sell a $$$ product but this is for a low-hit **website** where I sell my product.

I need to create those snazzy green 'buy' buttons, etc.

**Update:** It needs to be FREE.

Comment: What does "low-hit website" have to do with the question?

Comment: @Su' I was implying that said package must be NO COST or FREE. Illustrator is NOT FREE.

Comment: Um, you basically did everything *but* specify free or even cheap(until now), but okay sure. Next time actually say so up front. Trashing response as inapplicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) and [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) are good at handling vector graphics and works on both windows and linux. As for illustrator alternative for linux- check [sk1project](http://sk1project.org). You can create "buy buttons" using one of these applications.